# Локализация Laravel 5 - приложения, используя Middleware

Tags: laravel, locale

Работаю над разработкой блога с локализацией на разные языки. По одному из туториалов сделал это при помощи посредника - middleware. Все работает, но есть несколько проблем.
Во-первых, при смене языка каждый раз перебрасывает на главную станицу, а хотелось бы остаться на той же.
Во-вторых, главная страница, выглядит так: localost:8000/en ,потому что английский - язык по умолчанию. Но я не уверен что это хорошо для seo. Если стоит английский, то по идеи должно быть localost:8000. Пробовал решить это через сессии, но сессии не запоминали переменные. Вот код, который есть на данный момент:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class Language implements Middleware {

    public function __construct(Application $app, Redirector $redirector, Request $request)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->redirector = $redirector;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Make sure the current local exists
        $locale = $request->segment(1);

        // If the locale is added to to skip_locales array continue without locale
        if (in_array($locale, $this->app->config->get('app.skip_locales'))) {
            return $next($request);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // If the locale does not exist in the locales array continue with the fallback_locale
            if (!array_key_exists($locale, $this->app->config->get('app.locales'))) {

                $segments = $request->segments();
                array_unshift($segments, $this->app->config->get('app.fallback_locale'));
                return $this->redirector->to(implode('/', $segments));
                }
            }

    if (!$locale) $locale = $this->app->config->get('app.fallback_locale');

    $this->app->setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Как можно решить эти проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение Ваших проблем. 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/264435/

Выбранный язык хранится в сессиях. 
По умолчанию берется тот язык, который установлен в конфигах. 
Переключение происходит по переходу на страницу, с которой пользователя редиректит обратно.

Answer (score 3):

```
  <?php 

  namespace App\Http\Middleware;

  class Language implements Middleware {

      public function __construct(Application $app, Request $request)
      {
          $this->app = $app;
          $this->request = $request;
      }

      public function handle($request, Closure $next)
      {
        $fallback_locale = $this->app->config->get('app.fallback_locale');
        $locale = $request->segment(1, $fallback_locale);

        if (in_array($locale, $this->app->config->get('app.skip_locales'))) {
          return $next($request);
        } else {
          if (!array_key_exists($locale, $this->app->config->get('app.locales'))) {
              $segments = $request->segments();

              array_unshift($segments, $fallback_locale);

              return redirect()->back();
          }
        }

        $this->app->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
      } 
  }
```